# Media Source Extensions - Identifying when there is no more data

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4, media-source

I'm creating a fragmented MP4 of a real-time live content with constant 10FPS but occasionally a frame gets dropped before being feed to the MP4 creation process.
The MP4 is transmitted to the web through a web socket.

Due to the occasional frames drop, the playback speed of the file is effectively slightly greater than 1x, because the player plays at 10FPS.
Since this is a live content, after some duration, the player reaches the present time and has no data to play.

Now, to the MSE issue:
What seems to happen in Chrome, when the player doesn't have enough data to continue playing, is that it pauses for 1-2 secs, then plays it very fast, and vice versa. So at this point the user experience becomes very bad.
The issue was discussed here:
https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=28379

My idea to workaround this, is to identify the state (having no more data), change playback rate to 0.9 for a few seconds to allow some buffering, and then switch back to 1.0.
The problem is that I couldn't find a way to identify the state.
The readystate of the media element seems to always have the value of "HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA" even when the issue starts.

Does the MSE API exposes a way identify the state that I have described?